# Word for a person who gathers payments on behalf of other customers

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would clearly designate a person who takes individual payments from individual utility customers (e.g. his neighbours, friends or family) and goes to the utility (e.g. telecoms operator) payment office to pay in the global amount on their behalf.

He or she does not do this as an occupation but rather to help his fellows villagers (e.g. in a large country where the Points of Sales are sparsely distributed) and is himself a subscriber of this utility (albeit authorised for this role).

I would prefer to avoid *payment collector* which is altogether a different role in most utility jargons.

In addition, I'd also be willing to take suggestions for the individual payers (better than *contributors* for instance).

Comment: So this person is carrying paper currency on a journey to pay a utility bill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person providing the service is an ***agent***.

> **agent** *noun*
>   **1** a person who acts on behalf of another, in particular:
>   •    a person who manages business, financial, or contractual matters for an actor, performer, writer, etc.
>   •    a person or company that provides a particular service, typically one that involves organizing transactions between two other parties.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agent)

I would suggest ***client*** for those whose transactions he is managing.

Answer (score 1):

> fa·cil·i·ta·tor
> [fuh-sil-i-tey-ter]
>
> noun
>
> 1. a person or thing that facilitates.
> 2. a person responsible for leading or coordinating the work of a group, as one who leads a group discussion: Each committee will meet with its facilitator

source: dictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

Payment aggregator

Payment proxy

Fee agent

Difficult to tell. I'd be tempted to close this as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

Liaison

Communication or cooperation that facilitates a close working relationship between people or organization.

Answer (score 0):

This is, obviously, something that exists in some societies, but is altogether unknown in others. While the terms suggested in some of the other answers **could** be used for this purpose, there is **no** word that would be readily understood to have this meaning across the English-speaking world. If addressing a generic English-speaking audience, one would first have to explain at some length (as was done within this question) what such people do, and then introduce a term for them (which may be an adaptation of whatever term is used for them in the society in question).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a commercial arrangement, some words from economics and finance that could fit the bill are

1. *intermediary*
2. *middleman*

More informally, *go-between* can have a similar meaning.

Answer (score -1):

The person who collects utility payments from customers is typically referred to as a utility bill collector or a utility payment collector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP made it clear that *collector* would not be suitable for the purpose (it suggest that the person works for the utility, rather than to help fellow-subscribers).